# TaffyDB db().get() not returning an array of all the records

Tags: database, taffydb

I'm just starting to learn TaffyDB and am relatively new to programming in general and I'm not sure why what I'm trying to do isn't working.

Just a simple db to mess around and play with:

```
var sports = TAFFY([{name:"Washington Capitals", sport:"Hockey"},
                    {name:"Washington Redskins", sport:"Football"},
                    {name: "Washington Nationals", sport:"Baseball"}
                  ]);
```

And then I call `.get()` and want to return all of the names in the db

```
console.log(sports().get("name"));
```

This just returns an array of 3 objects containing all of the info inside the db. It doesn't specifically pull the names into an array.

Am I making the call wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
sports().select("name"); 
// returns ["Washington Capitals","Washington Redskins","Washington Nationals"]
```